# Cannot put text view in the right side of image in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to add a text view in the right side of an image in Navigation Drawer.

Here is my code,

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#FFA500">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profPic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_prof"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textName"
        android:textSize="15px"
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profPic" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTraveller"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textRecentViewed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Recent Viewed"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profPic"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPlacesNearBy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Places Near By"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textRecentViewed"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/slider_list"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textPlacesNearBy"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextLike"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="What do you like ?"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:layout_below="@+id/slider_list">
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

But, my text view always shown below the image. I don't see anything wrong in my code. Can anyone help? I need to get `textName` to the right side of `profPic`

Thanks :)

Edit -

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#FFA500">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profPic"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_prof"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textName"
            android:textSize="15px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTraveller"
        android:textSize="15px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Traveller"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTraveller"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textRecentViewed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Recent Viewed"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profPic"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPlacesNearBy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Places Near By"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textRecentViewed"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/slider_list"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textPlacesNearBy"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextLike"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="What do you like ?"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:layout_below="@+id/slider_list">
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you are using LinearLayout not RelativeLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#FFA500">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">\

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textName"
        android:textSize="15px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profPic"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_prof"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTraveller"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textRecentViewed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Recent Viewed"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profPic"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPlacesNearBy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Places Near By"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textRecentViewed"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/slider_list"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textPlacesNearBy"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextLike"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="What do you like ?"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:layout_below="@+id/slider_list">
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i updated check the edit my foult some code didnt show last time

Comment: Hi, But, I'm getting text view in the left side and image in the right side. But, I need the other way around. How did you get this. So, I can fix it. Thanks :)

Comment: just move textview below imageview

Comment: Hi, Do you have any idea how to put another text view below TextName? because when I'm trying to put another text view it goes in front of Textname

Comment: Can You just look at my edited code? because, I can't see my TextTraveller. Sorry for silly questions. Still strugling with these layouts since I'm new to Android. :)

Comment: remove android:layout_weight="1" from TextTraveller